# How to reset an image to default in Windows Form

Tags: c#, image

I have created a picture box in my Windows Form. I set it to a particular image in the Properties section. I then coded a method which changes the image depending on criteria. How would i reset the image to initial default image i had after it has been changed?

Comment: You mean you specified an Image in design time and you override it on run time?

Comment: yes. I set an Image in the design tab, then created a method to change the image depending on certain criteria. i need to know how to reset it to my initial image.

Comment: You can save the previous image to a field and when you want to reset simply assign the field value to the image field.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something as simple as:

```
pbMyImage.Image = pbMyImage.InitialImage;
```

This will reset it to the value you set in the InitialImage in the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply changing it to the default image again inside your code?

```
pictureBoxName.BackgroundImage = yourDefaultImage;
```

Aditionally, create a new void method and call for it whenever you want to reset it to default:

```
public static void setImageToDefault()
{
    pictureBoxName.BackgroundImage = yourDefaultImage;
}
```

Then call for the method `setImageToDefault();`

Comment: i hoped there would be a way to simply reset to default?

Comment: @user3541263 I'm not sure if there is such thing. You can create an explicit void method that does what I just wrote above and call for that method. Not sure if that suits you better.

Comment: Ok. I'll simply change it back to the initial image manually, as i did to change it from the initial...

Comment: i am new to C# but not Java. I'm experimenting with C# and was trying to expose myself to as many shortcuts as possible :)

Comment: @user3541263 Good luck, if you find a better solution feel free to post it here so I can learn something new aswell :)

Comment: :) will do. Thnx 4 ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

We can reset picture box to its initial image easily. You can also check this property set in resource file for required picture box. For example if name of our picture box is "picFacial" then we can reset it like

```
 System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(frmePassportApplication));

this.PicFacial.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("PicFacial.Image")));

this.PicFacial.InitialImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("PicFacial.InitialImage")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but hopefully this will help others stumbling upon the same issue ... you can put your particular image in the `ErrorImage` in section of properties window NOT in the `image` section .... then your code will be

```
private void btnDelImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pboxImage.Image = pboxImage.ErrorImage;
}
```